# Dual field paramters - Sales and Sales last year using field parameter is showing the same value in a matrix when filter to Accounting period. Why?

Tags: powerbi

I am using two field parameters in my matrix visual to show:

1. Total sales and total sales last year
2. Filter by Month-year and Accounting period

The matrix visual works fine when I filter on Month-Year. But it fails when I filter accounting period (my sales and sales LY are the same value).
The two parameters are linked in a 1 to many relationship.
[The two parameters are linked with a key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPEeO.png)

I have two relationship links between my main table (a.k.a Sheet 1) and the date table (a.k.a Date Table).

The two relationships are:

1. Sheet1[Order date] and Date Table[Date] - Inactive
2. Sheet1[Invoice date] and Date Table[Date] - Active

[Data model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3da1L.png)

My measure for Sales last year for Accounting period is as follows:

CALCULATE([Total Sales AC PERIOD], SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date Table'[Date]), USERELATIONSHIP(Sheet1[Invoice date], 'Date Table'[Date])

[Sample of my data Sheet 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E66cI.png)

[Sample of date table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KURiw.png)

[Total sales and sales LY are showing the same values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulm2v.png)

I have tried using various Timeintelligence Dax such as PreviousYear or Dateadd but the problem still persists.

I have also tried creating a third relationship between Accounting periods for Invoice and the 'Date table' column in my Date Table and using this for my USERELATIONSHIP DAX. But it is still showing the same value for total sales vs last year.

The calculation of the sales are actually correct but my earliest data is in 2022. The column for 01-2022 for sales last year is not supposed to show up for 01-2022. And the Sales last year column for 01-2023 is supposed to show 17,400 instead of 22,135 as shown in the picture. [Sales last year column for 01-2023 incorrect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKfLG.png)